# How to convert pptx slides to a single svg image with aspose slides?

Tags: svg, aspose, aspose-slides

I was able to convert each pptx slide to multiples/separate svg images with the following code:

```
//Getting last slide index
        int lastSlidePosition=presentation.getSlides().size(); 
        SlideEx slide =null;

        //Iterating through every presentation slide and generating SVG image
        for (int i = 0; i < lastSlidePosition; i++)
        {
            //Accessing Slides
            slide = presentation.getSlides().get_Item(i); 
            slide.writeAsSvg(new FileOutputStream(path + i + ".svg")); 
        }
```

But I whant to converte all pptx slides to a single svg file.

Answer (score 0):

The whole presentation cannot be saved to a single svg using Aspose.Slides. However, you can do

1. [Pptx to pdf](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Converting+Presentation+to+PDF)
2. And then [PDF to svg](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Convert%20PDF%20to%20SVG%20format) using Aspose.Pdf.